# Чи вірно казати "погана екологія"

Tags: терміни, синоніми, словосполучення

Звучить як неточність, не знайшла відповіді у Вікіпедії та найпоширеніших джерелах. Просто визначення слова "поганий" до терміну екології по смисловому наповленню не підходить.

Comment: Питання також у тому, чи правильно казати "вірно казати")))

Comment: Саме так, я про це писала,  вірним можна бути комусь, або собі)
А от мене цікавить нюанс про "погану екологію" тому що не можу закінчити доповідь;)

Comment: @АннаСолнцева, якщо вважаєте, що Ваше запитання сформульоване з помилкою, Ви за бажанням можете виправити його, написнувши «edit». (Але щодо слова «вірний» насправді ситуація неоднозначна, багато хто відстоює за цим словом право на інші значення, окрім лише одного «не зраджувати когось».)

Comment: Було б добре якби ви також додали чому саме ви вважаєте, що вони не підходять по смисловому наповненню. Дописи можна редагувати і після створення.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первісне і основне значення слова «[екологія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F)» — наука (розділ біології), що вивчає закономірності взаємовідношень організмів одне з одним і з навколишнім середовищем, функціонування надорганізмових систем.

Використання слова «екологія» в значенні «саме навколишнє середовище або його стан» напочатку було суто розмовним.  З цієї точки зору не можна казати «погана/хороша екологія» — так само, як не можна сказати «погана/хороша математика», «погана/хороша фізика» або «погана/хороша хімія». Найправильніше казати: «погана екологічна ситуація», «поганий екологічний стан», «погане екологічне становище», «погані екологічні умови» абощо; або без використання слова «екологія» — «поганий (-е) стан (-овище) довкілля (навколишнього середовища)» (навіть використання «погане довкілля / навколишнє середовище» видається з цієї точки зору правильнішим за «погана екологія»).

Але, з іншого боку, використання слова «екологія» в значенні «екологічна ситуація» (припускаю, початково — розмовному) настільки поширилося, що навіть увішло в тлумачні словники:

> **ЕКОЛО́ГІЯ**, ї, *ж.*
>
> <…>
>
> 2. Умови існування людини, рослин і тварин у певному регіоні; природа як сфера діяльності людини. <…>
>
> <sub>[(Зі «Словника української мови» в 20 томах 2010-х років.)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=25649&page=854)</sub>

Тобто «Словник української мови» 2010-х років фактично «взаконив» використання слова «екологія» в тому значенні, яке раніше вважалося неграмотним і [в «Словнику української мови» 1970-х–1980-х років було відсутнє](http://sum.in.ua/s/ekologhija). (З'явилося також переносне значення «чистота» — як от «екологія мови», «екологія культури» — але це поза темою питання.)

Але чи слідувати новим тенденціям, чи дотримуватися пуристичних поглядів на мову чи окремі слова — це вже особисте питання кожного.